# Xamarin forms: Increase the editor height based on the character count

Tags: xamarin.forms, height, editor

I have an editor like below in my xamarin forms project.

[image]

**When I type a message on it I need to increase the height of the editor based on the number of characters.**

Here is my complete code of bottom part, I added a frame layout for making the entry corners are round:

```
<StackLayout
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                x:Name="tweetBox"
                VerticalOptions="End"
                Margin="0,0,0,10"
                BackgroundColor="#f2f2f2"
                Orientation="Horizontal">

                <Image 
                     WidthRequest="25"
                     HeightRequest="25"
                     VerticalOptions="Center"
                     Source="ic_add_blue_xx.png"
                     Margin="10,5,-5,5">
                    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer
                            Tapped="ShowPicureOptions"
                            NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
                    </Image.GestureRecognizers> 
                </Image>

                <Frame
                    Padding="0"
                    Margin="5,5,0,5"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    CornerRadius="10">

                    <Editor 
                        x:Name="tweetText"
                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        VerticalOptions="Center"
                        FontFamily="Bold"
                        BackgroundColor="White"
                        TextColor="#959595"
                        AutoSize="TextChanges"
                        PlaceholderColor="#959595"
                        Placeholder="  Enter Message..."/> 
                </Frame>

                <Image 
                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                    WidthRequest="25"
                    Margin="5,5,10,5"
                    HeightRequest="25"
                    HorizontalOptions="End"
                    Source="ic_send_xx.png"> 
                    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer
                            Tapped="SendTweet_Icon_Clicked"
                            NumberOfTapsRequired="1" /> 
                    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                </Image>
            </StackLayout>
```

Comment: Your code is working perfectly for me. Instead of executing, Provide Text properly & check in windows forms previewer.

Comment: @CGPA6.4  For me, the no change in the height of the entry, tried after removing the frame but no change. The text is going in a single line, no multiple lines are coming.

Comment: @CGPA6.4  I created a sample project and this feature is working fine on there, but when I apply this to the main project it is not working. I added the entire code of my bottom part(+ image, editor and send icon) to the question, can you please check?

Comment: Remove `Orientation="Horizontal"` from `StackLayout` than it should work.

Comment: @CGPA6.4 Removing Orientation="Horizontal" from StackLayout is working, but the icons are in vertical format, I need those 3 icons on the bottom in the horizontal orientation

Comment: This is your different question. Ask in new thread.

Comment: @CGPA6.4 Changing stacklayout to grid solve all the issues, thank you very much for your comments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is built-in to Xamarin.Forms now. Simply use the `Editor` control and set the `AutoSize` property to `TextChanges`. Note that the auto sizing will not work when you set a `HeightRequest`.

More information here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/editor

Update: from the comments we resolved that replacing the StackLayout with a Grid helps you achieve the result. This is because a StackLayout just takes up the space that is (initially) taken up by its children. A Grid is able to grow dynamically.

Comment: Not working after adding autosize property. when typing message, the text is showing in the same line. Only a single line is showing, not going to the new line after completing the first line and no change in the editor height.

Comment: Please update your question with some code you have that is not working for you

Comment: I created a sample project and this feature is working fine on there, but when I apply this to the main project it is not working. I added the entire code of my bottom part(+ image, editor and send icon) to the question, can you please check?

Comment: Try replacing your `StackLayout` with a `Grid`

Comment: Changing stack to grid solve all the issues, thank you very much Gerald

Comment: Updated the answer to be more complete. Great it worked!

Comment: one more question, I am also like to set a maximum height for the editor, is that possible?

Comment: I think nothing is built-in for this. Probably the OS will have some kind of maximum. Else you will need to hook into the `SizeChanged` event of the `Editor` and implement something for it yourself

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on Android and was able to resolve that by setting the `IsSingleLine` property to `false` in a custom renderer.

Here is a gist of the renderer:

```
    protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<Editor> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged (e);
        if (Control != null)
        {
            Control.SetSingleLine(false);
        }
    }
```

It is weird that the official Xamarin.Forms documentation states that

> The Editor control is used to accept multi-line input.

However, its default settings on Android do not allow multiple lines.